# How can you use an object's property in a double-quoted string?

Tags: powershell, string-interpolation

I have the following code:

```
$DatabaseSettings = @();
$NewDatabaseSetting = "" | select DatabaseName, DataFile, LogFile, LiveBackupPath;
$NewDatabaseSetting.DatabaseName = "LiveEmployees_PD";
$NewDatabaseSetting.DataFile = "LiveEmployees_PD_Data";
$NewDatabaseSetting.LogFile = "LiveEmployees_PD_Log";
$NewDatabaseSetting.LiveBackupPath = '\\LiveServer\LiveEmployeesBackups';
$DatabaseSettings += $NewDatabaseSetting;
```

When I try to use one of the properties in a string execute command:

```
& "$SQlBackupExePath\SQLBackupC.exe" -I $InstanceName -SQL `
  "RESTORE DATABASE $DatabaseSettings[0].DatabaseName FROM DISK = '$tempPath\$LatestFullBackupFile' WITH NORECOVERY, REPLACE, MOVE '$DataFileName' TO '$DataFilegroupFolder\$DataFileName.mdf', MOVE '$LogFileName' TO '$LogFilegroupFolder\$LogFileName.ldf'"
```

It tries to just use the value of `$DatabaseSettings` rather than the value of `$DatabaseSettings[0].DatabaseName`, which is not valid.
My workaround is to have it copied into a new variable.

How can I access the object's property directly in a double-quoted string?

Answer (score 248, accepted):

When you enclose a variable name in a double-quoted string it will be replaced by that variable's value:

```
$foo = 2
"$foo"
```

becomes

```
"2"
```

If you don't want that you have to use single quotes:

```
$foo = 2
'$foo'
```

However, if you want to access properties, or use indexes on variables in a double-quoted string, you have to enclose that subexpression in `$()`:

```
$foo = 1,2,3
"$foo[1]"     # yields "1 2 3[1]"
"$($foo[1])"  # yields "2"

$bar = "abc"
"$bar.Length"    # yields "abc.Length"
"$($bar.Length)" # yields "3"
```

PowerShell only expands variables in those cases, nothing more. To force evaluation of more complex expressions, including indexes, properties or even complete calculations, you have to enclose those in the subexpression operator `$( )` which causes the expression inside to be evaluated and embedded in the string.

Comment: This works but I wonder if i may as well just concatenate strings as I was trying to avoid in the first place

Comment: @ozzy432836 You can, of course. Or use format strings. It usually doesn't really matter and comes down to personal preference.

Answer (score 24):

<sup>Documentation note: [`Get-Help about_Quoting_Rules`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847740.aspx) covers string interpolation, but, as of PSv5, not in-depth.</sup>

To complement [Joey's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1145822/45375) with a **pragmatic summary** of PowerShell's ***string expansion*** (string interpolation in *double-quoted* strings (`"..."`, a.k.a. ***expandable strings***), including in double-quoted [*here-strings*](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847740.aspx)):

- Only references such as **`$foo`, `$global:foo` (or `$script:foo`, ...) and `$env:PATH`** (environment variables) **can  *directly* be embedded in a `"..."` string** - that is, **only the variable reference *itself, as a whole* is expanded**, irrespective of what follows.

  - E.g., `"$HOME.foo"` expands to something like `C:\Users\jdoe.foo`, because the `.foo` part was interpreted *literally* - *not* as a property access.
  - To **disambiguate a variable name** from subsequent characters in the string, **enclose it in `{` and `}`**; e.g., **`${foo}`**.
    This is especially important if the variable name is followed by a `:`, as PowerShell would otherwise consider everything between the `$` and the `:` a *scope* specifier, typically causing the interpolation to *fail*; e.g., `"$HOME: where the heart is."` breaks, but `"${HOME}: where the heart is."` works as intended.
    (Alternatively, `` ` ``-escape the `:`: `` "$HOME`: where the heart is." ``, but that only works if the character following the variable name wouldn't then accidentally form an *escape sequence* with a preceding `` ` ``, such as `` `b `` - see the conceptual [about_Special_Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters) help topic).
  - To treat a `$` or a `"` as a *literal*, prefix it with **escape char. `` ` ``** (a *backtick*); e.g.:
    `` "`$HOME's value: $HOME" ``
- For anything else, including using **array subscripts** and accessing an object variable's **properties**, you must **enclose the expression in `$(...)`**, the [*subexpression operator*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#array-subexpression-operator--) (e.g., `"PS version: $($PSVersionTable.PSVersion)"` or `"1st el.: $($someArray[0])"`)

  - Using `$(...)` even allows you to embed the output from **entire commands** in double-quoted strings (e.g., `"Today is $((Get-Date).ToString('d'))."`).
- **Interpolation results don't necessarily look the same as the default output format** (what you'd see if you printed the variable / subexpression directly to the console, for instance, which involves the default formatter; see [`Get-Help about_format.ps1xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_format.ps1xml)):

  - **Collections**, including arrays, are converted to strings by **placing a *single space* between the string representations of the elements** (by default; a different separator can be specified by setting [preference variable **`$OFS`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Preference_Variables#ofs), though that is rarely seen in practice) E.g., `"array: $(@(1, 2, 3))"` yields `array: 1 2 3`
  - Instances of **any other type** (including elements of collections that aren't themselves collections) are **stringified by *either* calling the [`IFormattable.ToString()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.iformattable.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx) method with the *invariant culture*, if the instance's type supports the `IFormattable` interface<sup>[1]</sup>, *or* by calling `.psobject.ToString()`, which in most cases simply invokes the underlying .NET type's `.ToString()` method**<sup>[2]</sup>, which may or may not give a meaningful representation:  unless a (non-primitive) type has specifically overridden the `.ToString()` method, all you'll get is the full *type name* (e.g., `"hashtable: $(@{ key = 'value' })"` yields `hashtable: System.Collections.Hashtable`).
  - To **get the same output as in the *console***, use a subexpression in which you **pipe to [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string)** and apply `.Trim()` to remove any leading and trailing empty lines, if desired; e.g.,
    `` "hashtable:`n$((@{ key = 'value' } | Out-String).Trim())" `` yields:

    ```
        hashtable:                                                                                                                                                                          
        Name                           Value                                                                                                                                               
        ----                           -----                                                                                                                                               
        key                            value
    ```

---

<sup>[1] This perhaps surprising behavior means that, for types that support culture-sensitive representations, `$obj.ToString()` yields a *current*-culture-appropriate representation, whereas `"$obj"` (string interpolation) always results in a *culture-invariant* representation - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37603732/45375).</sup>

<sup>[2] Notable overrides:

• The previously discussed stringification of *collections* (space-separated list of elements rather than something like `System.Object[]`).

• The hashtable-*like* representation of `[pscustomobject]` instances (explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40253364/45375)) rather than the *empty string*.</sup>

Comment: Is there a proper name for `${..}`?

Comment: @AbrahamZinala, not that I'm aware of. Perhaps variable-reference-with-disambiguated-name-via-curly-braces-enclosure? (Just kidding.)

Answer (score 20):

@Joey has the correct answer, but just to add a bit more as to why you need to force the evaluation with `$()`:

Your example code contains an ambiguity that points to why the makers of PowerShell may have chosen to limit expansion to mere variable references and not support access to properties as well (as an aside: string expansion is done by calling the `ToString()` method on the object, which can explain some "odd" results).

Your example contained at the very end of the command line:

```
...\$LogFileName.ldf
```

If properties of objects were expanded by default, the above would resolve to

```
...\
```

since the object referenced by `$LogFileName` would not have a property called `ldf`, `$null` (or an empty string) would be substituted for the variable.

Comment: Nice find. I actually wasn't completely sure what his problem was but trying to access properties from within a string smelled bad :)

Comment: Thanks guys! Johannes why do you think accessing properties in a string smells bad? How would suggest it is done?

Comment: caveman: It just was a thing that caught my eye as being a potential error cause. You can certainly do it and it's nothing weird, but when omitting the $() operator it screams "Fail" because it can't work. Thus my answer was just an educated guess about what your poblem could be, using the first possible failure cause I could see. Sorry if it looked like it, but that comment wasn't referring to any best practice or so.

Comment: Good you had me worried there! ;) When I first started using powershell I thought the variable in a string was a bit weird, but it is quite handy. I've just not managed to find a definitive place that I can look for syntax help.

Answer (score 11):

@Joey has a good answer. There is another way with a more .NET look with a String.Format equivalent, I prefer it when accessing properties on objects:

Things about a car:

```
$properties = @{ 'color'='red'; 'type'='sedan'; 'package'='fully loaded'; }
```

Create an object:

```
$car = New-Object -typename psobject -Property $properties
```

Interpolate a string:

```
"The {0} car is a nice {1} that is {2}" -f $car.color, $car.type, $car.package
```

Outputs:

```
# The red car is a nice sedan that is fully loaded
```

Comment: Yeah that is more readable especially if you are used to .net code. Thanks! :)

Comment: There's a gotcha to look out for when you first use format strings, which is that you will often need to enclose the expression in parens. You cannot, for example simply write `write-host "foo = {0}" -f $foo` since PowerShell will treat `-f` as the `ForegroundColor` parameter for `write-host`. In this example you would need to `write-host ( "foo = {0}" -f $foo )`. This is standard PowerShell behaviour, but worth noting.

Comment: Just to be pedantic, the example above is not "string interpolation", it is "composite formatting". Since Powershell is inextricably bound to .NET for which C# and VB.NET are the primary programming languages, the terms "string interpolation" and "interpolated string" (and anything similar) should be applied only to the new $ prepended strings found in those languages (C# 6 and VB.NET 14). In these strings, parameter expressions are directly embedded in the string instead of numeric parameter references, with the actual expressions then being arguments to `String.Format`.

Comment: @andyb, regarding format string "gotchas". This is actually  the difference between **Expression** and **Argument** mode (see [about_Parsing](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_parsing)). Commands are parsed into **tokens** (groups of characters forming a meaningful string). Space separates tokens that would merge but is otherwise ignored. If the command's 1st token is a number, variable, statement keyword (if, while, etc), unary operator, {, etc... then the parsing mode is `Expression` otherwise `Argument` (up to a command terminator).

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use properties within quotes follow as below. You have to use $ outside of the bracket to print property.

```
$($variable.property)
```

Example:

```
$uninstall= Get-WmiObject -ClassName Win32_Product |
    Where-Object {$_.Name -like "Google Chrome"
```

Output:

```
IdentifyingNumber : {57CF5E58-9311-303D-9241-8CB73E340963}
Name              : Google Chrome
Vendor            : Google LLC
Version           : 95.0.4638.54
Caption           : Google Chrome
```

If you want only name property then do as below:

```
"$($uninstall.name) Found and triggered uninstall"
```

Output:

```
Google Chrome Found and triggered uninstall
```